# Ruby - How to use the hash_syntax gem?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rvm, ruby-1.9, ruby-1.9.3

I found this gem https://github.com/michaeledgar/hash_syntax

I don't quite understand how I can use it even though it seems a simple gem. Should I write

```
 hash_syntax --to-19
```

on the shell? Shouldn't I put something on the $PATH so it understands the command?

I also tried to run it through a ruby script (require gem and then run the above command) but it didn't work, it doesn't understand the command.

I've tried it on ubuntu 10.04, rvm and ruby 1.9.3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

actually installing the gem via `[sudo] gem install hash_syntax` should have put it in your PATH.

And yes, the syntax is pretty straightforward: `hash_syntax --to-19 FILE`.

You could also consult `hash_syntax --help`

Comment: Thank you it worked! I think I mispelled it multiple times, I can't explain it otherwise (I tried it more than 30 times). Where did you see that it put in the PATH the command hash_syntax?

Comment: the Gemfile normally helps... but bash-autocompletions answers these questions,too.

Answer (score 2):

You might want to use the other gem that solves the same problem but in slightly other way.
Install:

```
gem install syntax_fix
```

Run in the project root:

```
syntax_fix -v
```

As the result, all the hashes will be converted (including nested files and directories)